# MS Word add-in - get the contents of table pasted and linked from Excel

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

***EDIT*:** *The previously formulated question was a bit misleading, giving the impression that my intention is to use ActiveX object instead of a linked table.*

I'm developing an add-in for **MS Word** where I need to be able to retrieve data of tables that were copy-pasted from **MS Excel**. Tables are linked so that every change in Excel is reflected in Word. Here are the reproduction steps for a better picture:

1. Select the whole named table in Excel and copy to clipboard
2. In Word: choose "Paste Special"
3. In dialog: "Paste link" as HTML format (could be also a Formatted Text (RTF))
4. Now the data changes in Excel are immediately reflected in Word because of the linking

I'm struggling with the proper usage of Word API to programmatically select tables from the document and retrieve their data, possibly as plain JSONs and with underlying Excel formulas. This is how it's more-less done with the Excel API:

```js
Excel.run(function(context) {  
  var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");  
  var expensesTable = sheet.tables.getItem("ExpensesTable");  

  // Get data from the header row  
  var headerRange = expensesTable.getHeaderRowRange().load("values");  

  // Get data from the table  
  var bodyRange = expensesTable.getDataBodyRange().load("values");  

  // Get data from a single column  
  var columnRange = expensesTable.columns  
    .getItem("Merchant")  
    .getDataBodyRange()  
    .load("values");  

  // Get data from a single row  
  var rowRange = expensesTable.rows.getItemAt(1).load("values");  

  // Sync to populate proxy objects with data from Excel  
  return context.sync().then(function() {  
    var headerValues = headerRange.values;  
    var bodyValues = bodyRange.values;  
    var merchantColumnValues = columnRange.values;  
    var secondRowValues = rowRange.values;  

    // Write data from table back to the sheet  
    sheet.getRange("A11:A11").values = [["Results"]];  
    sheet.getRange("A13:D13").values = headerValues;  
    sheet.getRange("A14:D20").values = bodyValues;  
    sheet.getRange("B23:B29").values = merchantColumnValues;  
    sheet.getRange("A32:D32").values = secondRowValues;  

    // Sync to update the sheet in Excel  
    return context.sync();  
  });  
}).catch(errorHandlerFunction);
```

(taken from [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-tables#get-data-from-a-table))

My code so far:

```js
 Word.run(context => {
   const table1 = context.document.body.tables.getFirstOrNullObject();
   table1.load(["rows"]);

   const rows = table1.rows;
   rows.load(["items"]);

   return context.sync().then(() => {
     console.log("log", rows);
   });
 });
```

I need an advice on how to properly combine calls `<object>.load(<props>)` & `context.sync()` in order to retrieve the data I need.

Comment: You will *not* be able to retrieve the formulas. Word brings in *only* the data, not what generates it.

Comment: Too bad, fortunately the plain data is fine too! Formulas were "nice to have"

Comment: This question is still not very clear. How is the code you show not working? What is your *specific* question?